# Sort an ActiveRecord Relation using Geocoder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, rails-activerecord, rails-geocoder

I am using the Geocoder gem with a model called Breve. Geocoder provides with a method near([latitude, longitude], radius) returning a Relation containing all the "breves" in the radius of the reference point. I want create a view where there will be 2 lists of breves, 1 ordered in reverse chronological order of their last update time, and 1 based on proximity to a given reference point (in the following code, it is the center of Paris).

```
Breve.near(@reference_point,10)
```

when I test that line the Relation is actually sorted from the closest to the furthest breve from the reference point. However when I pass it to the view through the controller, it displays in reverse chronological order like the other list.

I have tried a couple of things but I couldn't figure it out so far. Here are below the code for the controller and for the view, and the Breve model :

```
controllers/static_pages_controller

require 'will_paginate/array'

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
def home
    @update_ordered = Breve.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @reference_point = [48.85, 2.35]
    ordered = Breve.near(@reference_point,10)
    #binding.pry
    @location_ordered = Breve.near(@reference_point,10).paginate(page: 
                                                      params[:page])
end

def content
end

def contribute
end
end
```

the view views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<div class="span5 pull-left">
<h3>Liste classée par date de dernière modification</h3>
<ul class="list">
    <%= render @update_ordered, detail: 'time_update' %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate @update_ordered %>
</div>
<div class="span5 pull-right">
<h3>Liste classée par distance au centre de Paris</h3>
<ul class="list">
    <%= render @location_ordered, detail: 'distance' %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate @location_ordered %>
</div>
```

and the model models/breve.rb

```
class Breve < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :description, :title, :location, :source_name, :source_URL, 
                        :latitude,:longitude
has_paper_trail
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

validates :title, presence: true
validates :title, :length => { :maximum => 100 }

validates :location, :length => { :maximum => 100 }
validates :description, :length => { :maximum => 2000 }
validates :source_name, :length => { :maximum => 100 }

validates :latitude, presence: true
validates :latitude, numericality: true
validates :latitude, :numericality => {
    :greater_than => -90,
    :less_than => 90
}

validates :longitude, presence: true
validates :longitude, numericality: true
validates :longitude, :numericality => {
    :greater_than => -180,
    :less_than => 180
}

default_scope order: 'breves.updated_at DESC'
end
end
```